# Pass argument to AsyncCallback function?

Tags: c#, function, arguments, asynccallback

I'm learning socket programming and I have the following function:

```
public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
```

and this is how the callback gets set:

```
pfnWorkerCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);
```

The problem is I need to pass another argument to OnDataReceived callback function, how can I do this? I'm trying to make a simple tcp server and I need to track from which client the data is coming from. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: [Asynchronous Delegates Programming Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h80ttd5f.aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to presume you're using `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` here. If you look at the overloads of [BeginReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceive.aspx) you'll see the `object` parameter (named state). You can pass an arbitrary value as this parameter and it will flow through to your `AsyncCallback` call back. You can then acess it using the `AsyncState` property of `IAsyncResult` object passed into your callback. Eg;

```
public void SomeMethod() {
  int myImportantVariable = 5;
  System.Net.Sockets.Socket s;
  s.BeginReceive(buffer, offset, size, SocketFlags.None, new new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived), myImportantVariable);
}

private void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult result) {
  Console.WriteLine("My Important Variable was: {0}", result.AsyncState); // Prints 5
}
```

Comment: @user1192403 Glad to hear it :)

Comment: What if we are going to pass multiple parameters?

Comment: Then you would have to use some kind of container for it;

`public class Foo {
  public int Bar {get;set;}
  public string Baz {get;set;}
}`

And then pass an instance of that into the `BeginReceive` method and cast `result.AsyncState` back to that type.

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem I prefer to solve with anonymous delegates:

```
var someDataIdLikeToKeep = new object();
mySocket.BeginBlaBla(some, other, ar => {
        mySocket.EndBlaBla(ar);
        CallSomeFunc(someDataIdLikeToKeep);
    }, null) //no longer passing state as we captured what we need in callback closure
```

It saves having to cast a state object in the receiving function.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `BeginReceive`, you can pass any `object` as its last parameter. The same object will be made available to your callback through `IAsyncResult`'s `AsyncState` property.

Answer (score 0):

As MrMDavidson mentioned.

> If you look at the overloads of `BeginReceive` you'll see the object parameter (named state)

You could pass an object array of your desired parameters to the `state` parameter and then deal with them later in the callback method.

```
client.BeginConnect(ipEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(ConnectedCallback), new object[] { parameter1, parameter2});
```