# Aynch Socket Connection - Passing parameters to Begin Accept

Tags: .net, sockets

Am working on asynchronous socket programming and am using this code

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example

Am dynamically creating these listeners(New instance of Socket Listener on each Port by passing different Port numbers and i need to pass an associated information for each port number when the socket is listening so i can use that information when i receive data.

basically my Start listening method will be like

```
public static void StartListening(string addInfo)
```

i understand how to pass additional parameter for Asynch function after referring this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9192678/1481690

but in this socket code we already passing socket as a parameter (Listener)

```
listener.BeginAccept(   
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),  
                    listener );
```

How do i add one more additional Parameter i need to pass on to **BeginAccept**?

what other ways i can get this to work as we already have a socket(Listener) object sent as a parameter.

or how else can i dynamically ramp up the socket servers with different ports and some how i can map additional Info to each Socket

Comment: The state parameter is whatever you'd like it to be. For example, an object which contains a reference to your listener, and whatever other parameter(s) you can think of.

Comment: @glenebob Exactly i understand that !!! but if you look at the Asynch program in details. it is already using the state parameter in   listener.BeginAccept and i cant change the class as it is "Socket"

Comment: You can't "add" any additional parameters to the call. Perhaps you could use an associative collection to map a socket object to additional data.

Comment: @glenebob  can you share some code with the sample i shared. am not quite catching up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle this, given that you cannot change the type of the state object in the call to BeginAccept().

1: Inject additional data into the callback code path:

```
AdditionalInformation additionalInformation = new AdditionalInformation(whatever);
listener.BeginAccept((asyncResult) => AcceptCallback(asyncResult, additionalInformation), listener);
```

2: Use an associative collection to store additional information. In this case, AcceptCallback would refer back to the collection to retrieve the additional information:

```
Dictionary<string, AdditionalInformation> additionalInformationMap = new Dictionary<string, AdditionalInformation>();

AdditionalInformation additionalInformation = new AdditionalInformation(listener, whatever, whateverElse);
additionalInformationMap[MakeKey(listener)] = additionalInformation;
listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
```

Comment: that helps to get some thing out of it. i can use Tuple to make it  simpler .. thoughts?

Comment: I don't see why Tuple wouldn't work, but I would avoid it. A well named class makes for more readable code than a Tuple does.

Comment: makes sense . in your option 1 what does the AcceptCallback method looks like . will it be parameter followed by state as last parameter?

Comment: AcceptCallback is the name of the callback method you used in the question, and is merely an example. It looks however you need it to look.

Comment: Can someone show working code based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example to pass additional parameter, let's say it is string myname = "I pass my name as a additional parameter";